# SQL Server Management Studio 17 problem Visual studio shell isolated

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ssms

I am getting this problem when trying to launch SQL Server Management Studio 2017. The installation finished with no problems.

[problem1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOAty.png)

I have reinstalled SSMS, C++ redistributables, .NET Framework 4.5 4.6 4.7, several times, and it keeps the same.

The only thing I can’t install is visual studio 2015 shell isolated. When I try to install, it says the following:

[problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIMp5.png)

If I uninstall .NET Framework, and try to install VS Shell isolated, it keeps poping the same screen but with a button of "Accept and install", then it begin to install .NET Framework 4.6 and the screen closes suddenly.

It seems the shell isolated doesnt recognize .NET Framework is installed already, but other software like Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition works perfectly.

It appears in control panel, but if I right-click it, says "change", and then the same screen saying .NET Framework appears.

[problem3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGPPh.png)

Any solution ?

EDIT: I could fix it upgrading to Windows 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it in this way : first I removed all the frameworks I could. After rebooting I removed all the visual c runtime I could. Then, I rebooted again.

After rebooting, I installed in order all the visual c runtime, each bundle in a couple, where x86 was the first. I skipped those who said they were already installed. Finally I installed the framework 4.5.

VS shell should install fine. The issue is due to visual c runtime 2015 being almost compatible with visual c runtime 2017. However, if you manually download and install each version in publication order, the detection should work correctly.

Warning: make a system backup before starting and download all the installers before starting the uninstallation, as after rebooting, certain software may fail as their dependencies could be missing (for example antivirus).

Comment: I did every step as you said and nothing, it keeps poping the same screen, thank you anyway.

Comment: I am sorry, this procedure fixed my setup. Which os are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 ultimate

Comment: Question, when you meant all the visual c++ redist, it was including Visual C++ 2017 redist, correct?

Comment: Yes, 2017 was the culprit (in my case) because it is said to be binary compatible with 2015, but for certain registry keys, the aren't. We haved the issue on all pre-installed laptops from different manufacturers.

Comment: I didnt test without installing C++ 2017 redist... anyway thanks, but I upgraded to Windows 10 and it works perfectly

Comment: The issue is related to C++ 2017 preventing the C++ 2015 being installed. So yes, you had to remove *all* them. Gald you fixed in a way or another:)